# Details of transactions of ERC20 tokens with special fees

Tags: transactions, erc-20, etherscan, uniswap

Some ERC20 tokens have special rules that affect transactions like:

- burning certain % of every transaction,
- taxing some % of every transaction and redistributing it back to all token holders or moving it to Uniswap pool.

However, if I use etherscan, these consequences of transactions are not shown.

For example, if a token has a special 10% burn rule in the contract and I use unisawp to exchange 100 tokens, etherscan will only show that 90 tokens have been moved to another account, but it will not show the details of what happened with those 10 remaining tokens. There is no record of that part of the transaction anywhere that I can find.

Also, if part of that special tax is redistributed to account holders, then those tokens will just appear in my account without record of how much and when.

Is there any way how one could get details of such transactions (like timestamps and amounts)?
In short, I would like to see the full transaction history that shows all tokens coming in my account and leaving it and if etherscan can't show me that, what do I need to do to get it?

Comment: Would love to know more about this as well...bump.